# Is it possible to use a database sequence for a non-PK field in a Grails app?

Tags: database, grails, grails-orm, sequence

In my application i need a unique value for a specific field in the database. This field has to be of type Integer. So i was wondering if it is possible to use a sequence for the field? And how to i implement that in my GORM domain class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the grails doc on how to [use sequences](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/id.html).  Depending on the source of the sequence ( (oracle/postgres) sequence number generator type / database table)

```
static mapping = {
    intField1 generator:'sequence', params:[sequence:'sequence_name']
    intField2 generator:'sequence', params:[table: 'hi_value', column: 'next_value', max_lo: 100]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Works nicely!