# Grails can not assigning sequence next value to a field using SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, grails, sequence, hibernate-mapping, grails-domain-class

I am using grails 2.5.2 and SQL Server database. I have created a sequence in my table `sp_support_ticket` named `TICKET_SEQ`. In my domain I am trying to map that sequence as follow:

```
static mapping = {
    table 'sp_support_ticket'
    ticketSequence generator:'sequence', params:[sequence:'TICKET_SEQ']
    ...
}
```

And my `TICKET_SEQ` looks as below:

[image]

But when I try to save the domain object, `null` value inserted in the field `ticket_sequence`. My question is how to set the next value of sequence in the field `ticketSequence` or will it take it automatically during save?

**NOTE:** I am not using native SQL or HQL

Comment: Is `ticketSequence` the primary key?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown no it's a Long type another field

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I _think_ we may only support `generator` in the `mapping` block for the primary key.  Have you seen any docs or samples that suggest otherwise?

Comment: Yes, `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814110/is-it-possible-to-use-a-database-sequence-for-a-non-pk-field-in-a-grails-app` - in Krock's answere

Comment: I believe that works, but that surprises. me.  I thought we only supported `generator` in that way for generating identifiers.  TIL